# Am trying to create a database with gorm by taking the users inpute using and api like structure e.g c.BodyParser(new(User))

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

```
var (
err  error
User []AcctDetails
```

)

type (
AcctDetails struct {
gorm.Model
ID           uint
AcctName     string `gorm:"default:John Doe"`
AcctNumber   string
UsersPhoneNo string
}
)

func CreateDb(c fiber.Ctx) error {
db := database.DB

```
c.BodyParser(new(User))
// user := User

db.Create(&User{ID: AcctDetails.ID, AcctName: AcctDetails.AcctName, AcctNumber: AcctDetails.AcctNumber, UsersPhoneNo: AcctDetails.UsersPhoneNo})
return c.JSON(User)
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use db.AutoMigrate(&AcctDetails{}).
This will create your table at the db.
db.Create will create a record and assign a value to the fields specified.